# How to write firebase database rules with this plugin "Firebase Authentication"

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I have used `signInWithVerificationId()` in my ionic Application. Every thing is working great. But i am not able to use Firebase database rules with this plugin. Below are my codes. Please help to implement database rules.

I used https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/firebase-authentication/ to authenticate users
and https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase to access firebase data.

**Function to send OTP**

```
send(){
  this.firebaseAuthentication.verifyPhoneNumber(this.mobile,60).then((data)=>{
    console.log(data) this.verificationId = data; alert('OTP SENT');
  },error=>{ console.log(error) }) 
}
```

**Code to login**

```
verify(){ 
  this.firebaseAuthentication.signInWithVerificationId(this.verificationId, this.code).then((verified)=>{
    if(verified=='OK'){ 
      console.log('user loggedin successfully') 
    } 
  },error=>{ console.log(error) }) 
}
```

**Code to fetch data**

```
this.firebaseAuthentication.onAuthStateChanged().subscribe((user)=>{
  if(user){ 
    console.log(user);
    firebase.database().ref('dummydata').on('value',snapshot=>{
      console.log('data ',snapshot.val()) 
    },error=>{ console.log('error ',error) 
  }) 
}
```

**Database rules**

```
{ "rules": { "dummydata":{ ".read": "auth!=null", ".write": "auth!=null" } } }
```

> Error: permission_denied at /dummydata: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(user)` that you have in the `onAuthStateChanged()`?

Comment: `{emailVerified: false
phoneNumber: "+917004187930"
providerId: "firebase"
uid: "LcomgHbSETh3Qxy3PoA8mpkgKzm1}"`

Comment: That looks correct, and the rules match with it. I don't know why this would raise an error. Hopefully somebody else sees it.

Comment: The error in my view is due to the plugin i have used for authentication because its not returning the instance of current user. But if we use `firebase-npm` for authentication it always return the instance of current user throughout the application. `firebase.auth().currentUser` is always null in case of plugin authentication.